# Effect of entring multiple characters for char type variable

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ coding.

I have noticed that if I enter multiple characters for a character variable then the test program given below goes into an infinite loop. I am not able to debug this issue properly. Can someone help me see how the flow of the program goes when such input is entered. I doubt about some unsafe conversions happening.

There is a possibility that the overflow values are taken as input for next integer variable, but I am checking for variable in a loop and asking the user to
re-enter a value is invalid. The program does not halt for taking new input for number. Instead it infinitely prints "Enter a Number". Why is it that the cin is not working for
taking the new input? Is there some modification in this program that can rectify this error?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char name;
    int number=-1;
    cout << "Enter a character: \n";
    cin >> name; //Use input like abc here
    cout << "number = " << number;
    while (number == -1)
    {
        cout << "Enter a number: \n";
        cin >> number; // This never waits for user input
    }
    return 0;
}


Output
Enter a character:
ytc
number = -1Enter a number:
Enter a number:
Enter a number:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the user enters mutiple characters on the first query, only the first one is extracted and stored in `name`.

After that, the loop is entered. The first character is read, and **it is not a number**, thus the stream goes into a bad state. All subsequent reads fail, so the value of `number` never changes, and you have an infinite loop.

The following program will do what you want:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  char name = '\0';
  int number = -1;
  std::cout << "Enter a character: " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> name;
  std::cout << "You entered " << name << std::endl;
  while(number == -1) {
    std::cout << "Enter a number: " << std::endl;
    if(!(std::cin >> number)) {
      if(std::cin.eof()) {
        std::cout << "User pressed CRTL+d" << std::endl;
        break;
      }
      std::cout << "This was not a valid number - try again: " << std::endl;
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.get(); // extract one character
    }
    else
      std::cout << "You entered " << number << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The condition `if(!(std::cin >> number))` checks if the extraction was successful. If not, an error-message is printed, the stream-state is cleared, and one character extracted. The latter is done to prevent an infinite loop, because if we never extract the bad character, we will get the same error over and over again.

Note that the extraction `std::cin >> number` will try to extract the longest string that represents a number. If the user inputs `234t23432`, then it will extract `234`, because the `t` is the first character that can not be interpreted as part of the number.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guaranteed method to clear an input stream. You can write code to clear but there's no surety that it will work. Because in standard C/C++ input streams are buffered. The keypresses are buffered by operating system, not by the program. You can recursively call cin.get() to make sure that all the data in the buffer is consumed. See the snippet below

```
char name = 0;
int number = -1;
std::cout << "Enter a character: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> name;
std::cout << "You entered " << name << std::endl;

// Clear the stream
while( !std::cin.eof() && std::cin.get() != '\n' );

std::cout << "Enter a number: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> number;
return 0;
```